# NodeJS - "ERROR: This Socket is Closed" intermittently

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, exception

Please see the below error which I am getting when calling a nodeJS route.
I am seeing the same exception in another route also. Both routes have methods which do MongoDB operation. This is intermittent and happens only with two API calls which deals with values in DB.

```
    {
  date: 'Thu Sep 15 2016 04:16:46 GMT-0500 (EST)',
  process: {
    pid: 4424,
    uid: 0,
    gid: 0,
    cwd: '***rootFolder***',
    execPath: '/usr/bin/node',
    version: 'v6.3.1',
    argv: [
      '/usr/bin/node',
      '**rootfolder**/app.js'
    ],
    memoryUsage: {
      rss: 104415232,
      heapTotal: 77893632,
      heapUsed: 60997696
    }
  },
  os: {
    loadavg: [
      0.03564453125,
      0.06103515625,
      0.0625
    ],
    uptime: 3184925
  },
  trace: [
    {
      column: 19,
      file: 'net.js',
      function: 'WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric',
      line: 672,
      method: 'Socket._writeGeneric',
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 8,
      file: 'net.js',
      function: 'WriteStream.Socket._write',
      line: 724,
      method: 'Socket._write',
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 12,
      file: '_stream_writable.js',
      function: 'doWrite',
      line: 307,
      method: null,
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 5,
      file: '_stream_writable.js',
      function: 'writeOrBuffer',
      line: 293,
      method: null,
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 11,
      file: '_stream_writable.js',
      function: 'WriteStream.Writable.write',
      line: 220,
      method: 'Writable.write',
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 40,
      file: 'net.js',
      function: 'WriteStream.Socket.write',
      line: 650,
      method: 'Socket.write',
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 16,
      file: 'console.js',
      function: 'Console.warn',
      line: 51,
      method: 'warn',
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 43,
      file: '*****/node_modules/express/lib/application.js',
      function: 'EventEmitter.logerror',
      line: 629,
      method: 'logerror',
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 20,
      file: 'timers.js',
      function: 'runCallback',
      line: 576,
      method: null,
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 5,
      file: 'timers.js',
      function: 'tryOnImmediate',
      line: 550,
      method: null,
      native: false
    },
    {
      column: 5,
      file: 'timers.js',
      function: 'processImmediate [as _immediateCallback]',
      line: 529,
      method: null,
      native: false
    }
  ],
  stack: [
    'Error: This socket is closed',
    '    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:672:19)',
    '    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:724:8)',
    '    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:307:12)',
    '    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:293:5)',
    '    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:220:11)',
    '    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:650:40)',
    '    at Console.warn (console.js:51:16)',
    '    at EventEmitter.logerror (***rootFolder***/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:629:43)',
    '    at runCallback (timers.js:576:20)',
    '    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:550:5)',
    '    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:529:5)'
  ]
}
```

Comment: have you checked the errors mentioned in stack []?